# get last repeat loop's result as vector in R

Tags: r

i want to create a vector of numbers (following weibulldistribution (shape=c,scale=b), the length is uncertain at the beginning of creating this vector (length depending on g)! using a function (c,b,g) with a repeat loop brings the result on screen, but not into the vector. So I need the last loop's result in a vector, but don't know how

```
t<-NULL
z<-NULL
p<-NULL
neededvector<-function(c,b,g) {
    p<-repeat{
        t<-rweibull(1,c,b)
        append(z,t)
        z<-print(append(z,t))
        if(sum(((z*0.01)^2*pi)/4)>g)
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: Repeat with me: "We do not incrementally grow an object in a loop, because that is slow. May we rot in the [Second Circle](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) of programming hell if we do."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally it's a bad idea to grow an object in a loop, since that's slow in R. If we knew your resulting vector were less than 1000, we could use `cumsum` to know when we should stop it:

```
neededvector <- function(c,b,g) {
    z <- rweibull(1000, c, b)
    z[((cumsum(z) * 0.01) ^ 2 * pi) <= g]
}
```

This solution won't work for you if the resulting vector should have been longer than 1000. But you can make it work, and be a lot faster than 1-at-a-time, by doing it in chunks.

```
neededvector <- function(c,b,g) {
  z <- c()
  while (TRUE) {
    # generate values 1000 at a time
    z <- c(z, rweibull(1000, c, b))
    threshold <- ((cumsum(z) * 0.01) ^ 2 * pi) <= g
    # check if this would include all elements of z.
    # if not, return it.
    if (sum(threshold) < length(z)) {
      return(z[threshold])
    }
  }
}
```

Generally, rather than 1000, set that value to some length greater than you generally expect the Weibull to be. (If your vector ends up being length 100,000, this method will have poor performance unless you set it to create it in chunks closer to that length).

Comment: It should also be mentioned that we can calculate the expected value of the Weibull distribution and use that to get a reasonable estimate of the final size of the result vector.